# c# LINQ how to determin a XElement with specific attribute

Tags: c#, linq

i would like to realize this functionality:
determin, whether the XML file has a XElement with specific attribute or not.
This is the example XML code:

```
<root>
    <pou objectId="name">
    </pou>
    <pou objectId="value">
    </pou>
    <pou objectId="address">
    </pou>
</root>
```

I would like to determin, whether the XML file has a specific XElement "pou" with attribute ObjectId "name" or not.

The following is my code in C# using Descendants

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\jsc\Desktop\TestForInherit.xml");
XDocument xNew = new XDocument();
xNew.Add(new XElement("root"));
if (xdoc.Descendants("pou").Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("objectId") =="name").Any()==true)
{
    xNew.Add(new XElement("pou", new XAttribute("objectId", "name")));
}
xNew.Save(@"C:\Users\jsc\Desktop\TestForInheritNew.xml");
```

If the xml file has the XElement with specific attribute value, then add thie XElement to the new XML file.

But unfortunatelly it does not work. Can anyone give me some advise.

Comment: You don't need to put `Any()==true`. `Any()` returns a boolean value so remove `==true`

Comment: try `xdoc.Descendants("pou").Where(x=> (string)x.Attribute("objectId") != null)`

Comment: thanks Mohamad, it works! it is very nice of you

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish - Drop the `(string)`.

Comment: @S3152148 welcone anytime, comment is added as an answer, please accept so other having your problem can see it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following syntax to check if there's an attribute with specific name:

```
xdoc.Descendants("pou").Where(x=> x.Attribute("objectId") != null)
```